# Youtube API problem - when searching for playlists, start-index does not work past 100

Tags: api, youtube

I have been trying to get the full list of playlists matching a certain keyword. I have discovered however that using start-index past 100 brings the same set of results as using start-index=1. It does not matter what the max-results parameter is - still the same results. The total results returned however is way above 100, thus it cannot be that the query returned only 100 results.
What might the problem be? Is it a quota of some sort or any other authentication restriction?

As an example - the queries bring the same result set, whether you use start-index=1, or start-index=101, or start-index = 201 etc:

1. http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/snippets?q=%22Jan+Smit+Laura%22&max-results=50&start-index=1&v=2

Any idea will be much appreciated!

Regards
Christo

Answer (score 0):

I made an interface for my site, and the way I avoided this problem is to do a query for a large number, then store the results. Let your web page then break up the results and present them however is needed.

For example, if someone wants to do a search of over 100 videos, do the search and collect the results, but only present them with the first group, say 10. Then when the person wants to see the next ten, you get them from the list you stored, rather than doing a new query.

Not only does this make paging faster, but it cuts down on the constant queries to the YouTube database.

Hope this makes sense and helps.